# Change CSS of some <li> inside <ul> with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, click

**First part** is to click on an image. That image and the images who preceed that image get the opacity of 1. The rest of the images stay at opacity 0.1.

**Second part** is when you click on "click one". It duplicates the whole . But the images that have opacity 0.1 should be in black and white and they should be unclickable.

**My question**: How do I change the CSS of some li inside a ul? In this case the li that have the opacity of 0.1 have to become in black and white. I'm only able to change all the li's. How can I disable the images that will be in black and white, so that they aren't clickable anymore?

**HTML**

```
<ul id="people">
    <li><img src="person.jpg" alt="person" id="img1"></li>
    <li><img src="person.jpg" alt="person" id="img2"></li>
    <li><img src="person.jpg" alt="person" id="img3"></li>
    <li><img src="person.jpg" alt="person" id="img4"></li>
    <li><img src="person.jpg" alt="person" id="img5"></li>
    <li><img src="person.jpg" alt="person" id="img6"></li>
    <li><img src="person.jpg" alt="person" id="img7"></li>
    <li><img src="person.jpg" alt="person" id="img8"></li>
    <li><img src="person.jpg" alt="person" id="img9"></li>
    <li><img src="person.jpg" alt="person" id="img10"></li>
</ul>

<ul id="people2"></ul>

<ul id="people3"></ul>

<div id="click1">click one</div>
<div id="click2">click two</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('ul li img').transition({
        opacity: 0.1,
        delay: 500
    }).on('click', function () {
        $(this).closest("ul").find("img").transition({ opacity: 0.1, delay: 500 });
        $(this).closest('li').prevUntil().addBack().find('img').css('opacity', '1');
    });
    $('#click1').on('click', function(){
        $('ul#people').clone(true).appendTo('ul#people2');
        **$('ul#people2 li img').css('opacity', '0');**
        $(this).off('click');
    });
    $('#click2').on('click', function(){
        $('ul#people2').clone(true).appendTo('ul#people3');
        $(this).off('click');
    });
});
```

Comment: Use `$( "ul li" ).eq( index )` for selecting the `li` with the `index` you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdfreeg9/) with following adjustments:

```
$('#click1').on('click', function(){
   $('ul#people').clone(true).appendTo('ul#people2');
   $("ul#people2 li img[style^='opacity: 0']").addClass('blackWhite').off("click");
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.blackWhite{
   filter: grayscale(100%);
   filter: url(#greyscale);
   filter: gray;
   -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
}
```

For this black and white effect I've just used the approach taken from here: http://demosthenes.info/blog/532/Convert-Images-To-Black-And-White-With-CSS
and added an SVG image to the HTML. There maybe better solutions, but just as example.

I've also added the complete transition.js - https://github.com/peteboere/jquery-transition/blob/master/jquery.transition.js - you seem to use at the beginning of the js-panel of the Fiddle as I didn't find an online source for including it as external resource. Your adjusted code is at the end of the js panel below the comment `/* stack code start */`